# Asymptotic expression for the following sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I found this problem on my book: if $\sum d_n$ is divergent, with $d_n \to 0$, and if the $D_n$ are its partial sums, we have $$\sum_{v=1}^{n}d_vD_v\simeq \frac1{2}D_n$$
where $\simeq$ means that the ratio of the two sides approaches $1$ as $n\to \infty$.

I'm suspecting that there is a typo in the wording of this problem, what do you think? If it's correct, how can I prove it?

Comment: It seems that right handed side should be $\frac{1}{2}{D_n}^2$.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If we suppose that $d_v\geqslant 0$ for all $v$, we can show that  $\ \displaystyle \sum_{v=1}^n d_vD_v \sim \dfrac{D_n^2}{2} $.

- I'll use twice the inequality  $\ a\, b\leqslant \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} $  with  $a=D_v$ and $b=D_{v-1}$.
- $d_vD_v=(D_v-D_{v-1})D_v=D_v^2-D_vD_{v-1}\geqslant D_v^2 -\dfrac{1}{2} \left( D_v^2+D_{v-1}^2\right)=\dfrac{D_v^2-D_{v-1}^2}{2} $
  Therefore:  $\displaystyle \sum_{v=1}^n d_vD_v \geqslant \dfrac{D_n^2-D_0^2}{2}$
- $d_vD_v=d_vD_{v-1} +d_v^2=(D_v-D_{v-1})D_{v-1}+d_v^2 = D_vD_{v-1}-D_{v-1}^2+d_v^2 \leqslant \dfrac{D_v^2-D_{v-1}^2}{2} +d_v^2$
  Therefore:  $\displaystyle \sum_{v=1}^n d_vD_v \leqslant \dfrac{D_n^2-D_0^2}{2}+\sum_{v=1}^n d_v^2$

So, we have
$$ -\dfrac{D_0^2}{2}\leqslant \sum_{v=1}^n d_vD_v -\dfrac{D_n^2}{2} \leqslant -\dfrac{D_0^2}{2}+\sum_{v=1}^n d_v^2   $$

The end of the solution is not difficult to find.

---

### If we don't suppose that $d_v\geqslant 0$

I have an example where it's false that  $\displaystyle \sum_{v=1}^n d_vD_v \sim \dfrac{D_n^2}{2}$

Comment: It remains to show that $\sum_{v=1}^{n} d_v^2 / D_n^2 \to 0$. Where did you use the fact that $d_v \ge 0$?

Comment: Also there's a minus typo at the second bullet

Comment: If $d_v\geqslant 0$, then $\lim D_n=+\infty$ (because $\sum d_v$ diverges). 
$d_v^2=o(d_v)$ and $\sum d_v$ diverges and $d_v\geqslant 0$. We can conclude that $\sum_{v=1}^n d_v^2 = o\left(\sum_{v=1}^nd_v)\right)=o(D_n)$. Then $\sum_{v=1}^nd_v^2 /D_n \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Alright! Got you!